# EF. Когда использовать 1 контекст, а когда несколько?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

При работе с Entity Framework можно обойтись одним контекстом базы данных, а можно распределить модели по нескольким. Вся работа идет в рамках одной бд, используется Code First.

Когда и зачем использовать несколько контекстов? Есть ли смысл использовать разные контексты при работе с одной бд?

Comment: Если ваша база будет как на [картинке](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRw1H.jpg),то думаю будет хорошо использовать несколько контекстов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всё зависит от размеров вашей предметной области. Иногда удобно разбивать предметную область на несколько независимых маленьких контекстов в рамках одной бд, это даст возможность очень легко разделить базу данных на несколько используя границы контекста. Ещё можно создать несколько частично пересекающихся контекстов с одинаковыми именами сущностей но с разным набором полей. В рамках одного контекста операции над всеми входящими в него сущностями можно выполнить в единой транзакции. Для того что бы понять нужно ли вам разделять бд на контексты почитайте про Bounded Context например на хабре (https://habrahabr.ru/post/232881/)